# Why is the empty set part of the topology in the following examples?

Tags: general-topology

I am studying topology from Munkres. Why is the empty set an element of the topology that is schematically represented in the picture ? [image]

Comment: The empty set and whole set X are always in every topology on X.  Always.  The empty set isn't drawn because... well, it can't be.

Comment: Well, you could draw a set not circling any of a,b,c. But it'd just serve to confuse readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty set is part of every topology -- by definition, a topology on a set $X$ , $\tau$, is a collection of subsets such that $\emptyset, X \in \tau$, $\tau$ is closed under arbitrary union, and $\tau$ is closed under finite intersection.

The empty set isn't drawn, but the other sets in the topology are drawn as encircling the appropriate points.

Comment: To the O.P.: Note that "$T$ is closed under finite intersection" means that $\cap F\in T$ for every finite $F\subset T,$ which  includes the case $F=\emptyset.$

Comment: $\tau$ is closed under finite intersection means that the intersection of a finite number of open sets (i.e. elements of the topology) is also open (in the topology).

Comment: @user254665 $\cap \emptyset = X$ so this does not imply the empty set is in it. Arbitrary unions do, as $\cup \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Comment: It is customary to define $\cap \emptyset$ as $\emptyset.$